How to include custom fields in a Stripe invoice generated by a Checkout Session with custom fields?
I'm using Stripe's hosted checkout with custom fields and it works. However, by the time the customer completes checkout by paying, the invoice is already generated and finalized (so can't be edited), and it's too late to get the custom fields out of the checkout_session.completed webhook and add them to the invoice. Is there a way to have custom fields from the checkout session appear on the invoice?
I'm not using an ecommerce platform like woocommerce. And obviously, I would prefer not to have to implement the checkout plumbing myself just to get a textfield onto the invoice (prevent payment occurring somehow during checkout, raising and modifying the invoice manually, charging the payment method, etc).

Seems that the only way is create-and-throw a Customer object with custom fields which would automatically be populated into your Invoice: https://docs.stripe.com/invoicing/customize#custom-field-inheritance.
If you want to reuse an existing Customer, you may want to edit its custom field and reset back after created the Subscription via Checkout Session.

Thanks, but it still wouldn't work as in a hosted checkout. By the time the checkout_session.completed event is received (the only way by which I may discover the value of the custom field prior to editing the customer), the invoice would already be paid.
